# Stack is Empty Exception in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I created a chatbot by Bot Framework and I implemented a Reset option in order to delete the conversation e grant to the user to begin a new conversation.

```
// MessageController.cs
public async Task Post([FromBody]Activity activity)  
{  
  await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog().DefaultIfException());  
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);  <- Stack is empty Exception
} 
// RootDialog.cs
private void ShowMenuOptions(IDialogContext context)      
{    
    var optionList = new List<string>() { "Info", "Support", "Reset" };
    string prompt ="How can I help you?";    

    PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, (IEnumerable<string>)optionList, 
        prompt, retry, attempts);
}    

private async Task OnOptionSelected(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result) 
{    
    try    
    {    
        string optionSelected = await result;    

        switch (optionSelected)    
        {    
            case "Reset":    
                context.Reset();    
                context.ConversationData.Clear();    
                context.PrivateConversationData.Clear();    
                context.UserData.Clear();    
                break;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

When an user chooses reset option, the bot answers with "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue."
Debugging the code I see that the exception triggers after context.Reset().

Can anybody help me and solve it?

Comment: Have you tried doing calling `context.Reset()` after the clearing of the databags? Also, what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Hi @StevenG. like this?   
context.ConversationData.Clear();
context.PrivateConversationData.Clear();    
context.UserData.Clear();
context.Reset();
The exception in "Stack is empty"

Comment: Yes, what occurs after you change the order? Are you still receiving the error message where the Stack is empty?

Comment: @StevenG Yes, the error was the same. I change the reset flow implementing global Reset message handler